# How do I close a Popup that contains Menu when one of the MenuItems is selected (DataGridCell)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, popup, menuitem

I am having a problem using a Popup that contains a dynamic Menu within a DataGridCell.  I can get the popup to appear just fine, and disappear when focus is lost by clicking anywhere else in the window.  But, I cannot get the popup to disappear when one of the MenuItems is selected.

Here is the XAML for my CellTemplate:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ToggleButton Content=" + "
                  FontWeight="Bold"
                  FontFamily="Arial"
                  Foreground="Green"
                  BorderBrush="Transparent"
                  IsThreeState="False"
                  DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                  Name="Button_AddDefinition">
    </ToggleButton>
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=Button_AddDefinition, Path=IsChecked}"
           StaysOpen="False"
           Placement="Right"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Button_AddDefinition}"
           AllowsTransparency="True">
        <Border CornerRadius="3"
                Background="WhiteSmoke"
                BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                BorderThickness="1">
            <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NewDefinitionTypes}">
                <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Menu.ItemsPanel>
                <Menu.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding StringFormat='New {0}'}"
                                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Popup}, Path=DataContext.NewDefinitionCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                        </MenuItem>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Menu.ItemTemplate>
            </Menu>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Definition, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableDefinitions}"
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                MouseUp="DataGridCell_ComboBox_MouseUp"
                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                Style="{StaticResource ValidationErrorStyle}">
    </ComboBox>
</DockPanel>
```

When I click the toggle button (i.e. the '+') I get the popup, dynamically populated to have a menu item each item.  Here is what it looks like:

[image]

When I click anywhere else outside the popup, the popup disappears (what I want).  But, when I click one of the items, I also want the popup to process the selection, and then the popup should go away.  That is what I'm looking for here.  How can I make the popup disappear once an item inside it is selected.  I'm working on an MVVM platform, so minimal code-behind is preferred, but not dogma.

Any ideas?

Comment: why dont you create a ContextMenu instead of creating a menu and placing it in popup?

Comment: Main reason is that I only want the menu of items to appear when the user clicks the '+' button.  The requirement is for user action to bring up the menu, and the requirement is to not use simple context menus (that's the route I would go if it were entirely up to me).  Can a context menu be specified, but "launched" from the toggle button/button in the row?